# Is there a way to calculate joint pdf of two mutually dependent random variables given pdf of one of the random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Initially I am having n pairs of Rayleigh random variables $(x_1,y_1),...(x_n,y_n)$ where $x_1,y_1,..,x_n,y_n$ are mutually independent. Now I am having a selection function, which selects a pair based on the two step process

step 1: find the minimum of each pair i.e of $(x_n,y_n)$

step 2: select the pair having maximum among the minimums selected.

I am able to get the pdf of max(min(pairs)) random variable that turns out to be
$$ 4nxe^{-2x^2}(1-e^{-2x^2})^{n-1} $$

Can anyone please help me in finding the joint pdf of the pair which are dependent on each other (if x is considered minimum of the selected pair, y should always be greater than x).

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You found distribution of $X$. $Y|X \sim R|R>X$ which will yield the joint.

Comment: @A.S. Assuming the $R/R > X$ mentioned by you as $f(Y)/Pr(Y>X)$ where X is a constant, I got the pdf of $ Y/X $ as $ 2ye^{-y^2}/e^{-x^2} $. So my joint conditional pdf is $$ f(X,Y|Y>X) = 8nxye^{-(x^2+y^2)}(1-e^{-2x^2})^{n-1} $$. From the above equation I am trying to find out the joint pdf using $$ f(X,Y) = f(X,Y|Y>X)Pr(Y>X) + f(X,Y|X>Y)Pr(X>Y) $$. But the resulting pdf does not yield to one when integrated. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: $f_{X,Y}=f_X\cdot f_{Y|X}$ and $f_{Y|X}=\frac {f_Y(y)[y\ge x]}{P(Y\ge x)}$. Your formula for pdf is for finding expectations, not for pdfs.